# Absolute positioning in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

It's easy to absolute position something using `remember picture` with TikZ, but it only works with pdfLaTeX.

I can get something working by using negative `vskip` and `hskips` (trial and error), but that is pretty annoying.

How can i position something on the top corner on the first slide without `remember picture`?

Comment: Why can't you use pdflatex?

Comment: I do, but my supervisor has to keep using lots of old postscript figures with psfrag.

Comment: You can use postscript code with `pdflatex` using package like [pst2pdf](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/entries/pst2pdf.html), [pst-pdf](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pst-pdf.html) or [pdftricks](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pdftricks.html). The latter explicitly mentions support for psfrag.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [`textpos`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package has been designed for absolute positioning of text and graphics on the page.

Comment: there is no alternative to `textpos`?

Comment: @pluton: There are alternatives to textpos: [atbegshi, esopic and everyshi](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/insert-graphic-at-precise-place-on-a-page/6821#6821).

Answer (score 36):

Here it is a simple solution taken from **Section 17.13.2** of [*Tikz & PGF* manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (section subtitle: *"Referencing the Current Page Node – Absolute Positioning"*).

For example, to put a figure in the top right corner, you can use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[xshift=-2cm,yshift=-2cm] at (current page.north east){%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{photo.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The key in the code above is the combination of `current page.north east` (which fixes the **reference point**), and the `xshift` and `yshift` variables (which shift the image from that reference point).

Naturally, you can use any other reference point like `current page.center`, `current page.south west`, etc. Then, just achieve desire absolute placement using `xshift` and `yshift`.

The list of reference points for `current page.blah` include eight major cardinal directions (`north`, `west`, `south`, `east` and the four in between), plus `center`. It is also possible to use any degrees (0-360), where 0 is `east` and 90 is `north` (for example, `current page.45` for the top right corner).

Comment: Why 2cm in the shift?

Comment: @LucasSoares Just an example. Notice where I say " just achieve desire absolute placement using `xshift` and `yshift`"

Comment: I would add that the use of `anchor=south east` can also be useful.

Comment: I found it more convenient to use
`\begin{textblock}{<width>}(<x>,<y>)
<text>
\end{textblock}`. Aha, and `\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}`.