# Insert graphic at precise place on a page

Tags: graphics, positioning

I would like to put a small graphic in the bottom right corner of a the title page of an article. Is there a way to specify a precise location for a graphic on a page (that has text on it)?

I've tried doing it with a `\parbox` but haven't been able to so far.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

- The [`textpos`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package is probably the easiest way to insert a graphic at an absolute position on the page.
- `eso-pic` can do the same and is capable of adding such picture commands to several or all pages.
- [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) could be used directly to hook into TeX's shipout mechanism to insert pictures. This package is used by `eso-pic` which might serve as the easier front-end.
- [`everyshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi) is an older package for the same purpose like `atbegshi`. It works but I would recommend the more modern `atbegshi`.
- if you would like to use TikZ: the current page node allows drawing on the current page using absolute coordinates. Have a look at [Abolute positioning examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/absolute-positioning/) in the TikZ example gallery.

Comment: another solution is [\leavevmode \makebox \put](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34929/194185)