# Put variable text at a fixed location on every beamer slide.

Tags: beamer, positioning

Is there an option that I can use within `\begin{frame}... \end{frame}` so that the enclosed text always appears at same location on different beamer slides?

Ideally, I want something like this:

```
\begin{frame}{slide title}
some-option{\bf mytext} 
.....
\end{frame}
```

What I want is that no matter what "mytext" is, and no matter what the stuff following it is "....", "mytext" is always placed at same location: just below the title, at the right corner.

I tried using `\hspace{..}\vspace{..}{\bf mytext}`, but I need to change the space values in every single slide manually. And even then, the placement looks only approximately same on slides (visually).

Comment: have you looked at the textpos package with absolute (option) positioning?

Comment: See also [Absolute positioning in beamer and LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/absolute-positioning-in-beamer-and-latex) and the answer to [Insert graphic at precise place on a page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/insert-graphic-at-precise-place-on-a-page/6821#6821) where 5 ways are described.

Comment: As already pointed out, `textpos` is the way to go here. Note, however, that `textpos` does not go well together with `pgfpages`, which is used internally by beamer for stuff like `[notes on second screen]`; some also use it to produce 4up handouts.  The problem is that `textpos` and `pgfpages` interact on the shipout level -- the textpos-placed material ends up on every pgfpage!

Comment: Just for sake of completeness: An often mentioned alternative to `textpos` that **does not work** is to employ tikz`s absolute positioning (via the `(current page)` node and the `[overlay]` option). With beamer frames I never got it working, it seems that the size of `(current page)` is somehow calculated on the fly by beamer and changes with the content.

Answer (score 8):

As already said, tikz can help you to do the job:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \node at (current page.north east) [left,yshift=-0.15\textheight] {\bf text};}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title 1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{title 2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

With the help of the [textpos](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package you can define a command that puts its argument at an absolute position; an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{everypage}

\newcommand\MyText[1]{%
  \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(.7\textwidth,1cm)%
    #1
  \end{textblock*}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First frame}
\MyText{\bfseries Text for the first frame}
Some test text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second frame}
\MyText{\itshape Text for the second frame}
Some test text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```