# How to add text to the corner of a Beamer slide?

Tags: beamer, positioning

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Absolute positioning in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/absolute-positioning-in-beamer)
>   [Put variable text at a fixed location on every beamer slide.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14688)
>   [How can I position an image in an arbitrary position in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/how-can-i-position-an-image-in-an-arbitrary-position-in-beamer)

I would like to know how to add text to the corner of one of my `beamer` slides. I would like this text to be just above the infoline at the the bottom right of the slide. I've looked into trying to use the `TikZ` package, but this package seems unnecessarily complex for my purposes. Can anyone help? I am using XeLaTeX.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Duplicate of [Absolute positioning in beamer and LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/absolute-positioning-in-beamer-and-latex), [How can I position an image in an arbitrary position in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/how-can-i-position-an-image-in-an-arbitrary-position-in-beamer) and/or [Put variable text at a fixed location on every beamer slide.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14688). I think this question should be closed, please state the existing threads don't fully answer your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `textpos` package could be an option; in the following example, the command `\FrameText` puts its argument ragged right, at the bottom right of the frame; change the settings according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\newcommand\FrameText[1]{%
  \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0pt,\textheight)
    \raggedright #1\hspace{.5em}
  \end{textblock*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test frame}
\FrameText{Some text}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test frame}
\FrameText{Some text for frame two}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution is great. Since this method uses absolute positioning, I have to adjust every slide if the length of this text changes. Is there a way to somehow right justify so that the text essentially starts against the right edge of the slide and then extends leftward? This would allow variable size text fields to all be right justified.

Comment: `\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(0pt,\textheight)\raggedleft Some loooooong text \end{textblock*}` -- note that this puts the text slightly further left than Gonzalo's initial answer.

Comment: @dr.bunsen: see my updated answer.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Remember we try to avoid duplicate material. :-)  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14688/put-variable-text-at-a-fixed-location-on-every-beamer-slide/14689#14689

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: You don't have to on my account.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. The only thing I can't figure out is how to control the vertical alignment. Your command puts the text slightly into my infoline.

Comment: @dr.bunsen: change the second length of the positioning argument; for example: `\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0pt,0.95\textheight)...`