# Epigraph in the end of the page

Tags: positioning, memoir, epigraphs

How could I position the epigraph in the end of the page, instead of at the beginning?
I'm using this preamble:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,11pt,a4paper,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,wasysym}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage[pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=darkgray, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

and this commands on the page intended to the epigraph:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\epigraph{O problema dessas citações na internet é a dificuldade para saber se elas são realmente autênticas.}{Friedrich Nietzsche}
```

I already tried to use **\vspace{}** and **\vfill**, and they dont work.

Comment: With the `memoir` class, you don't need to load the `epigraph` package -- `memoir` includes code equivalent to the package, and will ignore any attempt to load it.

Comment: If the page is empty before it, use `\vspace*{\fill}`, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @Stefan: yes, only the epigraph will be written on the page... but `\vspace*{\fill}` still dont do it.

Comment: @Stefan: sorry, _mea culpa_. I made a mistake... it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\epigraph` command typesets an epigraph at the point in the text where it is placed. So you can place it at the and of the page by inserting `\vfill` before:

```
\vfill
\epigraph{...}{...}
```

Since `\vfill` has no effect at the beginning of a page, use

```
\vspace*{\fill}
\epigraph{...}{...}
```

if you would like to push the epigraph down on an otherwise empty page. The starred version `\vspace*` forces whitespace which could otherwise be removed at the beginning of a page.

If you would like to write first the epigraph, then some text, but the epigraph should follow the text at the end of the page, you could use one of the options here: [Insert graphic at precise place on a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/insert-graphic-at-precise-place-on-a-page/6821#6821). This also applies to text boxes such as epigraphs. `textpos` would be easy. You just have to be careful to avoid overlapping then - writing linear would be easier.