# how to fix the position of a text in page when vspace is applied to other parts

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, epigraphs

I have an issue with using vspace. I have a page, blank with the following lines

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\begin{document}
\emph{Alpha Beta}
    \epigraph{\emph{An Alpha is a Beta when Gamma is dropped :D}}{\textit{a donkey}}
\end{document}
```

I want to put `\emph{Alpha Beta}` exactly in the center of the page, and `\epigraph{\emph{An Alpha is a Beta when Gamma is dropped :D}}{\textit{a donkey}}`  exactly at the bottom right of the page. I tried pushing the `epigraph` down with `vspace`, it works but the vspace moves `\emph{Alpha Beta}` aways from the center (pushes it up).

Comment: Did u have a look at  [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering)

Comment: and [Epigraph in the end of the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23938/epigraph-in-the-end-of-the-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions.  One uses `\smash` to hide the size of the text at the bottom.  The other uses tikzpagenodes to place things using absolute coordinate.  Note, it take two runs to work.

Because epigraph behaves badly, I put it into a minipage.  The [b] option prevents the text from dropping below the bottom of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\noindent\emph{Alpha Beta}
\vfill
\noindent\smash{\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
  \epigraph{\emph{An Alpha is a Beta when Gamma is dropped :D}}{\textit{a donkey}}
\end{minipage}}
\newpage\null
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[right,inner sep=0pt] at (current page text area.west) {\emph{Alpha Beta}};
  \node[above right, inner sep=0pt] at (current page text area.south west)
    {\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
      \epigraph{\emph{An Alpha is a Beta when Gamma is dropped :D}}{\textit{a donkey}}
    \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```