# Epigraph bottom page

Tags: spacing, memoir, epigraphs

Is there a more elegant way to keep the epigraph at the bottom of the chapter page (with no content-text)?

I could simply update/change the `\beforeepigraphskip` but that will cause me problems when the epigraph has more lines. I am trying to avoid extra packages since `memoir` already includes a lot.

I did try to follow [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23938/epigraph-in-the-end-of-the-page), but the solution did not work, maybe I am just adding the `\vfill` at the wrong spot. Hard to tell since OP did not include full MWE...

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[openleft]{memoir} 
\usepackage[]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.7\textwidth}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\setlength{\beforeepigraphskip}{32\baselineskip}
\setlength{\afterepigraphskip}{3\baselineskip}
%
\makechapterstyle{mykoma}{
    \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace{\beforechapskip}}
    \setlength{\beforechapskip}{2\onelineskip}%
    \setlength{\afterchapskip}{1.5\onelineskip}%
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{ }%
    \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}%
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\bfseries\normalsize}%
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter\space}%
    \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}%
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\bfseries\normalsize}
    \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\par \vspace{2ex}\rule{\columnwidth}{0.35cm}}
}

\begin{document} 
    \chapterstyle{mykoma}
    \chapter{Revisão Bibliográfica} \label{cha:revisao}
    \vspace*{-8ex}
    \epigraph{\blockquote{Someone said something really worth repeating.}}%
    {Not me, 1787, etc. }
    
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either redefine the way `\epigraph` works, inserting the appropriate spacing/content that suits your needs:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\epigraph}[2]{\par\vfill%\vspace{\beforeepigraphskip}
  {\epigraphsize\begin{\epigraphflush}\begin{minipage}{\epigraphwidth}
    \@epitext{#1}\\ \@episource{#2}
    \end{minipage}\end{\epigraphflush}
    \pagebreak%\vspace{\afterepigraphskip}%
}}
\makeatother
```

This replaces `\vspace{\beforeepigraphskip}` with `\par\vfill` (to push the epigraph down) and `\vspace{\afterepigraphskip}` with `\pagebreak`. Since [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) naturally sets its content using `\flushbottom`, `\pagebreak` will ensure a full stretch of the space above to have the epigraph at the bottom of the page.

Alternatively, keep the original definition and insert a hook to break the page after `\epigraph` with a `0pt` `\afterepigraphskip`:

```
\setlength{\beforeepigraphskip}{\fill}
\setlength{\afterepigraphskip}{0pt}
\AddToHook{cmd/epigraph/after}{\pagebreak}
```

Here is a complete minimal example using the latter approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass[openleft]{memoir} 

\usepackage[]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.7\textwidth}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\setlength{\beforeepigraphskip}{\fill}
\setlength{\afterepigraphskip}{0pt}
%
\makechapterstyle{mykoma}{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace{\beforechapskip}}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{2\onelineskip}%
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{1.5\onelineskip}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{ }%
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\bfseries\normalsize}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter\space}%
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\bfseries\normalsize}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\par \vspace{2ex}\rule{\columnwidth}{0.35cm}}
}

\AddToHook{cmd/epigraph/after}{\pagebreak}

\begin{document} 

\chapterstyle{mykoma}%
\chapter{Revisão Bibliográfica} \label{cha:revisao}
\vspace*{-8ex}
\epigraph{%
  \blockquote{Someone said something really worth repeating.}}%
    {Not me, 1787, etc. }
    
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```