# How to insert text outside the top margin?

Tags: positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert graphic at precise place on a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/insert-graphic-at-precise-place-on-a-page)

I am trying to insert my name on the top right corner of the page but outside the top margin. How can I do that? Many thanks!

Comment: The [texpos package](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) was designed for absolute positioning.

Comment: @PeterGrill: it's textpos ;-)

Comment: Are you sure you don't actually just want a header using the fancyhdr package for example? You can position to the right using that.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use `TikZ` with the `overlay` and `remember picture` options:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=40mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\path (current page.north east) ++(-1,-1) node[below left] {Peter S. Ilie};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

The `lipsum` package is just for blind text, the above produces

[image]

Comment: This is, basically, exactly what the `background` package does ;-)

Comment: Now that you mention it, the `current page.north east` should have cought my eye :) Also, looking in the `background` manual: "Since the commands used to modify attributes of the background material depend on the \node construct offered by the TikZ package...", so yeah, theres a package for doing what I did manually. You live and learn!

Answer (score 4):

Using [the `textpos` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{textpos}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.85\textwidth,-2cm)
My Name
\end{textblock*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works for me and requires little code.  The `showframe` option is not necessary.  The `textblock` should be located after `\maketitle` if you are using that.

Answer (score 3):

There's a number of packages allowing you to achieve what you desire; in the answer to this question there's a list of such packages: [Insert graphic at precise place on a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/insert-graphic-at-precise-place-on-a-page/6821#6821) . Another option, not listed in the linked answer is the [background](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetBgContents{The Author}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgPosition{current page.north east}
\SetBgVshift{-2cm}
\SetBgHshift{-2cm}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```