# How to display a picture flush to the right side of the page and the bottom?

Tags: graphics, positioning, titles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Absolute positioning in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/absolute-positioning-in-beamer)
>   [Insert graphic at precise place on a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/insert-graphic-at-precise-place-on-a-page)

I would like to add a picture to my title page, however, for effect, the picture needs to be aligned with the right side of the paper and the bottom of the paper.

How can I do this? I'm using `scrartcl` as main `documentclass`. I'm not averse to using the `titlepage` environment, I just haven't used it before (and also I wouldn't know how to do this on a normal page).

Edit: this is what my relevant code looks like:

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\vfill\hfill\includegraphics{../front_minifig}
\pagebreak[4]
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak[4]

\section{Lorem}
```

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may still use `\maketitle` using [textpos](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) or [eso-pic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic). For example

```
\documentclass[titlepage=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Option demo ist only for demonstration! Please
                           % remove it at your real document!
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \makebox(\paperwidth,0)[rb]{\includegraphics{demo}}%
  }%
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: The title page]

Answer (score 3):

Use `vfill` to push things to the bottom and a `\hfill` to make it go to the right:

[image]

Here I use [the `geometry` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/) just to show the frame:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove [demo] for real example
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\vfill\hfill\includegraphics[width=5.0cm]{foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, this doesn't work in my current setup, it seems to respect margins, is that correct?

Comment: Without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) it is difficult for me to help further. I have included the image that shows that it is properly paced with respect to the margins.

Comment: Using `\vfill` and `\hfill` to move something to the right bottom corner of the paper (not the text area!) is not a nice job.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I wanted it _outside_ the margins. Tried your answer and of course it works as you said! (It was just not what I meant, thanks again for helping!)

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Even though this is not what the OP wanted, it would be useful if you would elaborate on the downsides of using `\vfill` as that is not something I have used often.