# How to place inline figure

Tags: wrapfigure, inline

I am trying to create a resume with a picture. So i want the picture to be on the right hand side while the text is written on the left. With a bit of googling, I found wrapfigure package to insert the image. Now the problem is that after inserting using wrapfigure, the whole page is vertically divided into text and image sections, so I cant write any text below the text.

Here is how it looks now: (Cross is the image)

[image]

This effect is seen in the following page also. Is there any alternative or a improvement to this method itself?

A MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.15\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=40mm,width=35mm]{foto.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{document}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\author{My Name}
\date{May, 2012}
\maketitle

\section*{\sl Personal Information}
    Date of Birth   :   DD.MM.YY \\
    Citizenship     :   Country \\
    Visa Status     :   Status \\
    Passport Number :   XYZ \\
    Gender      :   Gender \\
    Marital Status  :   Status \\
    Languages known :   langs

You will understand more if u insert more text in this sentence. The more the text, the clear u can see the line break.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. [Here](http://pastebin.com/PuhuEvDp) is the MWE.

Comment: @gkris: Please put all information and images into the post. You can edit it using the 'edit' link below it. Posts there should be self contained. Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official stackexchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: CTRL+G). This ensures that all images are always accessible and do not expire. As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A mod or high-rep user can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `wrapfigure` environment is placed before `\begin{document}`. All content must be placed in the `document` environment. The `wrapfigure` must be also placed just before the text paragraph which should wrap around the figure. I'm not sure if it works well with `\section` etc.

If you want to write a CV or resume you should use a dedicated class for this. The [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) class is very well suited and allows you to add your image easily. See the [`moderncv`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/moderncv) manual for more information.

An alternative would also be to use the solutions shown for [Insert graphic at precise place on a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6817/2975). I wouldn't use `wrapfigure` for this specific case. It should be possible to place the images in such a way that there is now text flowing over it anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had inserted the wrapfigure above the `\begin{document}` tag just to move the image more upwards. Anyways I had a look at the moderncv template, and it looks suitable for me, i will use it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the [wrapfig](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package should work fine. It seems to me (since you didn't post any code, I can't be sure) that your document is multicolumn, in which case `wrapfigure` might have problems generating the proper cutout. Here is a workaround, published on CTAN: [Using wrapfig to span multiple columns](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig). Hope that helps.

Comment: @gkris: The `wrapfigure` environment is placed before `\begin{document}` in your MWE. All content must be placed in the `document` environment. The `wrapfigure` must be also placed just before the text paragraph which should wrap around the figure.