# Insert a figure on the corner of the page

Tags: positioning

I am using the following title page:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage[squaren,Gray]{SIunits}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{0.9,0.1,0.8,0.1}

\DeclareFixedFont{\titlefont}{T1}{ppl}{}{it}{0.5in}

\makeatletter                       
\def\printauthor{%                  
    {\large \@author}}              
\makeatother
\author{%
   \textcolor[RGB]{35, 127, 82}{\textbf{Pafuncio PAFUNCINHO}} \\
 \textit{  Bla bla bla bla bla}  \vspace{5pt} \\
\textcolor[RGB]{35, 127, 82}{\textbf{Zilcleio ZILCLEINHO}}\\    \textit{BLa bla bla bla}
    \texttt{}\vspace{5pt} \\
    \textcolor[RGB]{35, 127, 82}{\textbf{Coiso COISINHO}}\\       \textit{ Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
    \texttt{}
    }


        \newcommand\titlepagedecoration{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shorten >= -10pt]

        \coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=-15pt]current page.north east);
        \coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=-410pt]current page.north east);
        \coordinate (aux3) at ([xshift=-4.5cm]current page.north east);
        \coordinate (aux4) at ([yshift=-150pt]current page.north east);

        \begin{scope}[titlepagecolor!40,line width=12pt,rounded corners=12pt]
        \draw
          (aux1) -- coordinate (a)
          ++(225:5) --
          ++(-45:5.1) coordinate (b);
        \draw[shorten <= -10pt]
          (aux3) --
          (a) --
          (aux1);
        \draw[opacity=0.6,titlepagecolor,shorten <= -10pt]
          (b) --
          ++(225:2.2) --
          ++(-45:2.2);
        \end{scope}
        \draw[titlepagecolor,line width=8pt,rounded corners=8pt,shorten <= -10pt]
          (aux4) --
          ++(225:0.8) --
          ++(-45:0.8);
        \begin{scope}[titlepagecolor!70,line width=6pt,rounded corners=8pt]
        \draw[shorten <= -10pt]
          (aux2) --
          ++(225:3) coordinate[pos=0.45] (c) --
          ++(-45:3.1);
        \draw
          (aux2) --
          (c) --
          ++(135:2.5) --
          ++(45:2.5) --
          ++(-45:2.5) coordinate[pos=0.3] (d);   
        \draw 
          (d) -- +(45:1);
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        }

\begin{document} 

    \begin{titlepage} 




    \noindent
    \titlefont Blablablablabla  \\ Blabl Blabla
    \epigraph{Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\\ \vspace{2mm}  \textcolor[RGB]{35, 120, 82}{\textit{Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.}}}%
    {\textsc{XXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXXX}\\ \textit{September 15, 2014, Neuch\^atel, Switzerland.}}
    \null\vfill
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \noindent
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.70\linewidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            \printauthor
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
    %
    \begin{minipage}{0.02\linewidth}
        \rule{1pt}{125pt}
    \end{minipage}


\titlepagedecoration
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

As I did not create this template, I don't really know how to use it. I would like to add a logo on the left corner, at the bottom. How could I do this, please?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/insert-graphic-at-precise-place-on-a-page) could help even though you know nothing about what is on the current page.

Comment: If this is the start to a larger document, be aware, that tikz and soul make compiling slower. Maybe you don't need them for writing the document, only for the finish (titlepage etc.)? If so, think about commenting out them for the given time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this. use of `tikzpicture` at the end. Here the proposal use reference point at `(current page.center)` then use `shift={(x,y)}` options, where x<0 and y<0 (3rd quadrant), to move the logo to the lower left corner. Of course, you could have use `(current page.sout west)` and use shift option with (x>0, y>0) to allocate the logo position.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[shift={(-5cm,-8cm)}] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{soul,graphicx}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage[squaren,Gray]{SIunits}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{0.9,0.1,0.8,0.1}

\DeclareFixedFont{\titlefont}{T1}{ppl}{}{it}{0.5in}

\makeatletter                       
\def\printauthor{%                  
    {\large \@author}}              
\makeatother
\author{%
   \textcolor[RGB]{35, 127, 82}{\textbf{Pafuncio PAFUNCINHO}} \\
 \textit{  Bla bla bla bla bla}  \vspace{5pt} \\
\textcolor[RGB]{35, 127, 82}{\textbf{Zilcleio ZILCLEINHO}}\\    \textit{BLa bla bla bla}
    \texttt{}\vspace{5pt} \\
    \textcolor[RGB]{35, 127, 82}{\textbf{Coiso COISINHO}}\\       \textit{ Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
    \texttt{}
    }
        \newcommand\titlepagedecoration{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shorten >= -10pt]

        \coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=-15pt]current page.north east);
        \coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=-410pt]current page.north east);
        \coordinate (aux3) at ([xshift=-4.5cm]current page.north east);
        \coordinate (aux4) at ([yshift=-150pt]current page.north east);

        \begin{scope}[titlepagecolor!40,line width=12pt,rounded corners=12pt]
        \draw
          (aux1) -- coordinate (a)
          ++(225:5) --
          ++(-45:5.1) coordinate (b);
        \draw[shorten <= -10pt]
          (aux3) --
          (a) --
          (aux1);
        \draw[opacity=0.6,titlepagecolor,shorten <= -10pt]
          (b) --
          ++(225:2.2) --
          ++(-45:2.2);
        \end{scope}
        \draw[titlepagecolor,line width=8pt,rounded corners=8pt,shorten <= -10pt]
          (aux4) --
          ++(225:0.8) --
          ++(-45:0.8);
        \begin{scope}[titlepagecolor!70,line width=6pt,rounded corners=8pt]
        \draw[shorten <= -10pt]
          (aux2) --
          ++(225:3) coordinate[pos=0.45] (c) --
          ++(-45:3.1);
        \draw
          (aux2) --
          (c) --
          ++(135:2.5) --
          ++(45:2.5) --
          ++(-45:2.5) coordinate[pos=0.3] (d);   
        \draw 
          (d) -- +(45:1);
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        }

\begin{document} 

    \begin{titlepage} 
    \noindent
    \titlefont Blablablablabla  \\ Blabl Blabla
    \epigraph{Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\\ \vspace{2mm}  \textcolor[RGB]{35, 120, 82}{\textit{Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.}}}%
    {\textsc{XXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXXX}\\ \textit{September 15, 2014, Neuch\^atel, Switzerland.}}
    \null\vfill
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \noindent
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.70\linewidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            \printauthor
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
    %
    \begin{minipage}{0.02\linewidth}
        \rule{1pt}{125pt}
    \end{minipage}
\titlepagedecoration
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[shift={(-5cm,-8cm)}] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```