# Love message at the end of a document after references with Teddy pictures?

Tags: graphics, appendices

I am trying to write a love message at the end. I tried `\hfill\mbox` thing but could not get them working as intended, see below and [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18710829#18710829). It requires somehow making background images that go over the document. I would also love to make it so that the last page number is missing to make it more rebellious.

> **How can I make a love message at the end of document with all references?**
>
> 1. In way it would be super awesome if there were beautiful Teddy bears looking here and there over the document, is it possible? Like over marginals randomly over the document?

You can find the Teddy [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1I6C.png).

**Goal**

> [image]

**So far**

> [image]

Comment: `\printbibliography \thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{\fill} \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/teddy} \end{document}`

Comment: Possible duplicates: [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169808/5764) and [Insert graphic at precise place on a page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6817/5764)

Comment: @Werner Actually the other question is about analysing while my question is about synthesis: doing a specific thing with MWE so they are compatible and complementing each other. Please do not remove this thread, this is so super cool way to help others to do the same cute thing in LaTex :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\usepackage{tikz}` to your preamble, and this at the end:

```
\printbibliography

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=south east] at ([shift={(2.3in,-1.3in)}]current page.south east){\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/LoveNalle}};
\node[] at ([shift={(0cm,2in)}]current page.south west){\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/LoveNalle}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the dimensions in `shift` as you like.

Or put this entire thing in the preamble

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\AtEndDocument{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=south east] at ([shift={(2.3in,-1.3in)}]current page.south east){\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/LoveNalle}};
\node[] at ([shift={(0cm,2in)}]current page.south west){\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/LoveNalle}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Please remember that this can be done with `eso-pic` and `picture` mode also (just to make David happy ;)......).

Comment: That is so super amazing, I wish I could vote this up million times! Far cooler than the other thread with bullet points, thank you! It is so beautiful, Gesa will be amazed ^-^

Comment: @hhh: All the best and have a nice time ;-)

Comment: Sure ;) Before that I want to still perfect one thing: is there any easy way of adding the same template to many pages like also pages 1 and 7? I am totally new to this format. Where is the last page specified?

Comment: @hhh: If you want this for *all* pages, use `background` or `eso-pic` (`\AddToShipoutPictureBG`) package. If it is for *some* pages, you have three options. `\BgThispage` from `background` package, `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` from `eso-pic` or the above code with `tikzpicture`, any one of these should be put approximately in that particular page.

Comment: @hhh For example, put the content of `tikzpicture` above in `HostoryPolitics.tex` after `\subsection{Author's future projections}`. And before `\noindent Advisor: Professor Jon.....` in `tap.tex`. Compile 2 times. Check pages 1 and 7.