# crosshair in the middle of a page

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, page

How to draw a crosshair (with specific colour, and line width and height) in the middle of a every page (centered vertically and horizontally). Its position should not affect or be affected by other graphics and text in the page.

This is what I tried so far

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
These 2 lines are centered vertically and horizontally on a page
\hspace{0pt}
\vfill
\begin{center}
\rule{.4\textwidth}{2pt} I \rule{.4\textwidth}{2pt}
  \end{center}
\vfill
\hspace{0pt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Insert graphic at precise place on a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6817/5764)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This uses Ti*k*Z and places a cross hair at the page center, extending some size to the top/bottom and left/right margins, the dimensions of this is used from the 1st and 2nd arguments of the macro `\crosshair`. The 3rd argument is meant for colour etc. settings.

Please compile twice to get the node anchor placement correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\crosshair}[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,opacity=0.2]
  \draw[black, line width=2pt,#3] ($(current page.center)-(#1,0)$) -- ($(current page.center)+(#1,0)$);
  \draw[black, line width=2pt,#3] ($(current page.center)-(0,#2)$) -- ($(current page.center)+(0,#2)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\crosshair{5cm}{10cm}{blue}
\blindtext[10]
\crosshair{10cm}{2cm}{red,dashed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update for crosshairs on every page with `everypage` package**

Use the `\AddEverypageHook` macro in order to add some code that should be used on every page, i.e. place the `\crosshair` macro inside `\AddEverypageHook` as has been done in the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\crosshair}[4][opacity=0.2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,#1]
  \draw[black, line width=2pt,#4] ($(current page.center)-(#2,0)$) -- ($(current page.center)+(#2,0)$);
  \draw[black, line width=2pt,#4] ($(current page.center)-(0,#3)$) -- ($(current page.center)+(0,#3)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\AddEverypageHook{\crosshair[opacity=0.5]{5cm}{10cm}{blue}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can this code be repeated on every page, instead of repeating the line  \crosshair{5cm}{10cm}{blue}!

Comment: @Hany: See the update at the end of my answer

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to place content in the `F`ore`G`round in the centre of every page:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor,lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageCenter{%
    \color{red}%
    \makebox[0pt]{\rule{250pt}{2pt}}%
    \makebox[0pt]{\rule[-250pt]{2pt}{500pt}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use also `\watermark` or `\leftwatermark` and `\rightwatermark`  for even/odd pages, or  `\thiswatermark` for a particular page:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{watermark,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\begin{document}
\thiswatermark{\color{red!50}\rule{.5\textwidth}{0pt}%
\rule[\dimexpr-1\textheight-\headsep]{1pt}{1\textheight}}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```