# Grid to facilitate positioning of objects with \put in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning, grids

In presentations with the `beamer`package I use `\put` a lot to place graphic objects like this:

```
\newcommand{\putat}[3]{\begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)\put(#1,#2){#3}\end{picture}} % just a shorthand
\putat{123}{45}{stuff}
```

Now I was thinking about writing a small macro to facilitate finding the x and y coordinate by just writing a grid of positions onto the slide from which I can read off which values to use as arguments to `put`:

```
\newcounter{xpos}
\newcounter{ypos}
\forLoop[20]{20}{200}{xpos}{%
  \forLoop[10]{20}{100}{ypos}{%
    \putat{\value{xpos}}{\value{ypos}}{(\arabic{xpos},\arabic{ypos})}
 }
}
```

(This uses the `forloop` package.)

The problem is that I forgot that `put` uses relative positions (apparently). Can I somehow return to the same origin in every pass of the loop?

Or is there a simpler way to generate this grid?

Comment: Related question: [Absolute positioning in beamer and LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6185/215)

Comment: Does `textpos` work together well with `beamer` and graphics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi the most simple way seems to be using beamer itself:

```
   \setbeamertemplate{background}[grid][step=10]
```

Of course you could use full power tikz:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\tikz{
    \foreach \x in {-5,...,5} \draw (\x ,-5) -- (\x ,5) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {-5,...,5} \draw (-5,\y) -- (5,\y) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};}}
\begin{document}
\frame{hi world}

\end{document}
```

I´m aware that this solution is not a bare latex one. Nevertheless i believe this is the most comfortable way.

Comment: Cannot use `tikz`. We only have a way outdated version here, because we are stuck with CentOS :(
Your first suggestion seems to work though (if I replace `10` by `10pt`).

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig: You can use/update LaTeX package independent from the binaries. You don't need to use the version provided by our OS. Simply make your own `texmf` tree.

Comment: Well `step` normally expects a lenght however an up to date tikz/beamer obviously accepts a dimension free figure too. I guess, that it is replaced with an default dimension.

Comment: Number without an unit will be taken as multiple to the specific unity vector, which can be something very simple like an unit or something more complex like a 3-D vector. But do not mix numbers with and without units in the same expression because then `pt` are assumed!