# How can I position an image in an arbitrary position in beamer?

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning

I am making a presentation using `beamer`, and I want to be able to position a certain image the way I want in a frame. I am not sure how to do that.
Is there some way you can specify coordinates in the frame and then set an image there?

Is there a better way to place images in various places with the `beamer` class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute positioning in beamer and LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6185/2975), but I wouldn't mind more explicit answers for it.

Answer (score 64):

When I used such an application, I used either TikZ (my favorite), or, before knowing of TikZ, I used the textpos package.

I will briefly discuss both solutions.

## TikZ

I suggest to use a TikZ `\node` with `overlay` option.

NOTE: there are two ways to use TikZ here: one with RELATIVE positioning (the approach discussed below) and one with ABSOLUTE positioning (please refer to the TikZ manual for such a task).

The `overlay` means that it has no bounding box, i.e. it won't affect the existing layout.
I wrote a short-cut macro around to simplify the generation of such a node. To use it, place the following code into you beamer document:

```
\tikzset{
  every overlay node/.style={
    draw=black,fill=white,rounded corners,anchor=north west,
  },
}
% Usage:
% \tikzoverlay at (-1cm,-5cm) {content};
% or
% \tikzoverlay[text width=5cm] at (-1cm,-5cm) {content};
\def\tikzoverlay{%
   \tikz[baseline,overlay]\node[every overlay node]
}%
```

So, the basic idea is a `\node[overlay]` which aligns well within the usual text (the `baseline` option). You will need to use the `at (<x>,<y>)` positioning to actually place it. The placement will be relative to the embedding text. Keep in mind that you may hide text with this thing (which is the purpose of the `every overlay node` style as you guessed correctly). Note that text later in the document is always typeset after earlier text passages. In other words: make sure the `\tikzoverlay` command comes after things you want to hide.

An example could be

```
Here is the text which will probably be hidden by the overlay.
\tikzoverlay[text width=6cm] at (9.3cm,5cm) {
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \emph{Derive subclass} from \texttt{GetOptWrapper}
  \item one \emph{variable definition} per option
  \item \emph{Default Values}
  \end{itemize}
};
```

You can safely combine this with beamer's `\only<2>` methods.

## textpos

The second promised approach uses the `textpos` package. Since I think that this approach is weaker and less configurable than the one above, I simply copy-paste from my personal notes:

According to my old notes, the general usage is:

```
\usepackage{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm} % horizontal unit
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm} % vertical unit
...
\begin{textblock}{WIDTH}(OFFSET_X,OFFSET_Y)
CONTENT
\end{textblock}
...
```

Example with the package configuration above:

```
\definecolor{boxcol}{gray}{0.89}
\begin{textblock}{3}(8,-3)
\fcolorbox{black}{boxcol}{%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1cm}%
A notice that was put in the page using coordinates
\end{minipage}
}%
\end{textblock}%
```

Comment: If you use `textpos` with `beamer`, you likely want the `overlay` option, as in `\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}`.

Comment: How do the commands work with only the title page i.e. you want to have the logo only on the title page not on other pages? I am using the ready commands such as `\maketitle` should I use `\begin{titlepage}` and configure the titlepage like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59672/titlepage-with-tikz)?

Answer (score 56):

Solution **without defining new variables or calling extra packages** (other than *Tikz*):

For example, to put a figure in the top right corner, you can use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[xshift=-2cm,yshift=-2cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics{photo.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The key is in the combination of `current page.north east` (which sets the anchor) and `xshift={...},yshift={...}` (which moves the node from that anchor). Notice that you can use any other anchor like `current page.north west`, `current page.south west`, `current page.center`, etc.

For more information, see **Section 17.13.2** of the *Tikz* manual (it's just one page long).

Comment: Where do you place this tikz command in Title page of beamer document? I could not get it working inside author -command, other?

Comment: @hhh for the title slide, follow [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21356/adding-custom-image-in-title-slide).

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer that worked best for me. It was much less clear how to modify the accepted answer to get good control over the position (it seemed to interact poorly with slide content).

Answer (score 5):

The following code snipped uses `remember picture` for positioning.

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{frame}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
\node[anchor=north east] at ($(current page.north east)+(0,-1)$) {
  Top-right float content.
};

Regular content.
\end{frame}
```

It also uses the `calc` tikz library to specify an **offset from the top left corner** for positioning of the node, relative to the upper right corner. This will likely be a popular use case for positioning logos. X is right, and Y is up, so you will want negative offsets.

Comment: The `\tikz` macro and the `tikzpicture` environment are strictly equivalent...

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. In my case, I needed to nest another (sourced) tikzpicture, and I didn't want to stack a tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture, but apparently that would have worked reasonably well (I believe I have some errors because of that...) Also, I didn't get newlines working (as usual with tikz nodes) without specifying a node width.