# Adding custom image in title slide

Tags: beamer, graphics, titles

I use `beamer` with the `warsaw` style to create presentation. I would like to insert an image in the title slide as part of customization. An image that fills the whole breadth of the slide but limits to half height. How to do it. Couldn't find proper direction from `beamer` user guide

Comment: Where exactly should the image go (at the top of the frame, below the author,...)? Which is the expected final layout for the title page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Note that in (La)TeX the term *width* is used instead of *breadth*.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Need to place the figure in bottom of the title. Dont want the footer section in the title slide too.

Comment: Then, follow Martin Scharrer's advice and use one of the avilable fields to place the image. You can suppress the footer using the `plain` option for the frame.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can add an image on the title slide in `beamer` using `\titlegraphic{<image command>}`. Its position is dependent on, i.e. defined by, the used theme.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{Fooing the Bar}
\author{A.~Thor}
\institute{MWE Lmt.}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.5\textheight]{someimage}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can place an image inclusion macro in one of the other title page macros, e.g. `\institute{...}` is good for adding the institute name as well as the logo. You are allowed to use line breaks there.

```
 \institute{Foo Research Institution\\[\medskipamount]
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.5\textheight]{imgfilename}%
 }
```

Finally, you also can place the logo on an absolute position of the titlepage using `tikz` or `textpos`. Here an example using `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{Fooing the Bar}
\author{A.~Thor}
\institute{MWE Lmt.}
\titlegraphic{\vspace{8cm}}% to push the other text to the top

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \tikz [remember picture,overlay]
    \node at
        ([yshift=3cm]current page.south) 
        %or: (current page.center)
        {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.5\textheight]{someimage}};
   \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I use the first approach which is great but I would like to make a modification. I do not wish to use the author or date variable and I set them to null, and I would like to bring the image further upwards to replace the space that is allocated for those fields. can this be done?

Comment: @Vass: I don't know by heart, but you can simply post this as a follow-up question.

Answer (score 6):

If you want that appair the logo in all slices I think that you need the option logo in the preamble(for example after of the option \author)

```
\logo{\includegraphics[scale=#]{image-ubication}}
```

where # is a number between 0 and 1 and is used to scale the size of image. I use with theme PaloAlto!

Comment: You need to be aware that: 'The position wherethe logo is inserted is determined by the current theme; you cannot (currently) specify this position directly.'(quoted from the Beamer manual - ver. 3.12) So you should just experiment a bit and find out if it suits your layout.

Comment: Exactly, That's correct, for that reason I specify that I use PaloAlto theme.