# Beamer: problem of repetition of the logo on each page

Tags: beamer, graphics

I have a problem inserting an picture  at the beginning. Once I compiled, I have the picture on each page but I want to have the picture just on the first page.

Here is my code:

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \let\Tiny=\tiny
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
 \usepackage{type1cm}

 \usetheme{CambridgeUS} % theme

\title[automata]{ automata}
 \subtitle{Lucian Ilie} 
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute} 

\date{26 Mars 2012 \\ 

\includegraphics[width=1cm]{./image/logo_ur.jpg}

}
```

Comment: You have to use it inside a `frame` environment. Like this: `\begin{frame}\includegraphics{...}\end{frame} \begin{frame}my second slide\end{frame}`.

Comment: Closely related: [Adding custom image in title slide](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21356/3323)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You include your image in the `\date` variable. Beamer publishes the date on every slide (at least in most themes). That's why the logo is shown on each slide.

You will need to include the `\includegraphics[width=1cm]{./image/logo_ur.jpg}` in the first frame (titleframe)

Furhermore `Beamer` also provides a macro called `\logo{}`. You can use this command `\logo{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{./image/logo_ur.jpg}}` to draw the logo **on each (!) page**. I know your question wants to avoid this. Logo however places the logo on a location that should be elegant given the theme.

Answer (score 4):

The `\date` macro is obviously not the right place for a logo. There are two commands designed for drawing one instead:

- The [`\logo`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsubsection.8.2.5) command [has already been mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48686/3323). It draws a logo on each page.
- The [`\titlegraphic`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#page=94) macro looks much more suited to your needs: It inserts the graphic only on the title page, underneath the date.

#### Full example code for `\titlegraphic`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{type1cm}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS} % theme

\title[automata]{ automata}
\subtitle{Lucian Ilie} 
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute} 
\date{26 Mars 2012}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{./image/logo_ur.jpg}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}
   Content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: title page with logo inserted wby \titlegraphic]