# How to wrapfigure in Beamer Title Slide?

Tags: beamer, wrapfigure

I want to use a wrapfigure in my title for a Beamer presentation. When I try, the document fails to compile. Right now, I'm sneaking the images in under the authors. Is there a correct way to do this?

What I specifically want is the three author names stacked vertically, with their corresponding images at the bottom right of the page, horizontally at the same level.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}


\title[Short title]{
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{figures/ibl_logo_2.png}\\
2020 Annual Meeting\\Theory Working Group}

\author{Rylan Schaeffer, Leenoy Meshulam, Ila Fiete
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.16\textwidth]{figures/leenoymeshulam.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.16\textwidth]{figures/ilafiete.jpg}
}

\date{} % necessary to omit date

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *a wrapfigure* ?

Comment: By the way this is probably what you are looking for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21370/141947