# Beamer page numbering: Figure disappears

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, wrapfigure

I am trying to get my frames numbered. I'm trying it with the command 
`\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]`

But it's not really working... I have a logo on my title page, which disappears with the above command. If I use `\begin{frame}[plain]` for my title page, the logo AND the section overview (I'm using the theme `Goettingen`) on the right disappear.

Is there a way to fix this? Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames, handout]{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=MidnightBlue]{structure} 
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Goettingen}
   \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\title{title of the pres}
\subtitle{..}
\author{me}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.47\textwidth}
  \vspace{60pt}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{logo}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Background}
\begin{frame}
   first frame....
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'm happy about any ideas :)

Comment: The `wrapfigure` in the preamble doesn't make sense. Did you forgot a `\logo{..}` around it? Even then I personally wouldn't use `wrapfigure`. Also the `\bibliographystyle` line should be in the preamble.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Okay so now I'm trying it with 
`\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{mylogo}}`
and the section-bar on the right doesn't disappear. Looks a lot better than before, but I'd still like the logo to be right of the text of the titlepage (I mean on the right of my title and date and authorname). That's why I tried it with wrapfigure.

Comment: @Cammie: I see. Using `wrapfigure` on its own in the preamble like above is definitely wrong. It must be placed inside of the `\title{..}` or `\titlegraphic{..}` or similar macro. You could try `\title{The title\rlap{\hspace{<distance>}\includegraphics[<options>]{<filename>]}}}` to place it to the right of the title. Please don't forget to update your example above with any new code.

Comment: hmm... getting closer! But the figure still isn't next to the text, but creates a whole lot of space at the bottom. I used it like this: 

`title{Title of my talk}`
`\subtitle{ \vspace{2mm} \small A subtitle \\\vspace{4mm}\footnotesize ABC Conference 2011\\ University of ABC  }`
`\author{Cammie Lastname \\ Cammie's University}`
`\date{\footnotesize{\today}}`
`\titlegraphic{ \rlap{\hspace{8cm}\includegraphics[width=2cm]{unilogo}}}`

like I said, ideally, I'd like to have the logo on the right lower side of all the info. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also have a look at [How can I position an image in an arbitrary position in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/how-can-i-position-an-image-in-an-arbitrary-position-in-beamer).

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found a way: with this package 
`\usepackage{textpos}` 
I can create the titlepage like this:

```
\begin{frame}\vspace{1cm} 
     \begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\linewidth}
       \maketitle 
     \end{minipage} 
     \begin{textblock*}{2cm}(7cm,-5.0cm) 
       \includegraphics[width=2cm]{figurename} 
     \end{textblock*} 
\end{frame}
```

and everthing looks great.