# How do I customize Beamer template?

Tags: beamer, themes

I need to create a custom Beamer presentation theme for my company. I need to do the following:

- Include company logo in the header of each slide
- Include large company logo in the center of the `titlepage` background
- Modify the font colors

How do I do each of these tasks? I'd appreciate some details.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

My solution will let you know how to perform the modifications you need by customize a template as example.

I think the first thing to do is to select one of the existent themes as starting point.

Let's suppose to have chosen the `Copenhagen` theme. This MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\title{The title}
\author{My name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{The title of the frame}
hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

allows you to get:

[image]

[image]

As second step, let's now include a logo in each frame. You can apply the method reported in [Positioning logo in the front page as well as slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27906/positioning-logo-in-the-front-page-as-well-as-slides27920#27920) (in general to position the logo in an arbitrary position you could follow the explanation of [How can I position an image in an arbitrary position in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/how-can-i-position-an-image-in-an-arbitrary-position-in-beamer16362#16362) ). I applied the first one and I used just a test image, thus the result is not very good, but the important thing is the idea behind. Now your MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{textpos} % package for the positioning

\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\title{The title}
\author{My name}
\date{\today}

% position the logo
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(\textwidth,-1cm)
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{logopolito}
\end{textblock*}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{The title of the frame}
hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and your second frame:

[image]

Let's now add to the title frame a big logo in background. Before doing next passages, I recommend you  (not only for this one in particular, but also to change font color), to read carefully the whole code of the starting theme adopted: this will allow you to know how it is composed and what to modify.

To add a large logo in background I used the standard template `background`: since this will be applied to all frames, I made it transparent for all frames that are not the title page. Perhaps people more expert than me will say that this is not a good method, but I used it two or three times and I think it works pretty well.

The required code is:

```
\usepackage{tikz,calc}

\pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{logo}{logopolito}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight); 
    \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{0}{0},left,base]{\pgfuseimage{logo}};
  \ifnum\thepage>1\relax%
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
      \fill[white, opacity=1](0,\the\paperheight)--(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight)--(\the\paperwidth,0)--(0,0)--(0,\the\paperheight);
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

In few words, I declared the image with the size of the full frame ,then I put it inside the template `background` making a test on the current frame number: if it is not 1 (the title page), I make it invisible setting the opacity to 1.

After this step, the title page becomes:

[image]

which actually is very bad because I don't see anymore the author and the date. This is the reason why till now I did not care about colors: at this moment, seeing the partial result it is possible to take better choices; if instead I first decided colors and then put the image, maybe I would had to modify them again.

In this part is really important that you know how is built your starting theme. This one uses as `innertheme` `rounded` (that suggest you why the title is put in a rounded box) and as `colortheme` `whale` and `orchid` (you are interested in `whale` since `orchid` defines block colors). No definition are given for the `fonttheme` thus it uses `default`. Moreover, I noticed that the definition of the `title page` is not contained in `rounded`, so the `default` has been used (a note if you need to modify it).

I adopted several colors as examples: if I really would had to realize a theme it is not a good choice. Just remember that you can use each time a background color (`bg`) and a foreground color (`fg`) for the text.

The final example is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{textpos} % package for the positioning
\usepackage{tikz,calc}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\title{The title}
\author{My name}
\date{\today}

% position the logo
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(\textwidth,-1cm)
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{logopolito}
\end{textblock*}}

\pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{logo}{logopolito}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight); 
    \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{0}{0},left,base]{\pgfuseimage{logo}};
  \ifnum\thepage>1\relax%
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
      \fill[white, opacity=1](0,\the\paperheight)--(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight)--(\the\paperwidth,0)--(0,0)--(0,\the\paperheight);
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Color modification
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red!70!black}% to modify  immediately all palettes
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=yellow}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=yellow}
\setbeamercolor{author}{bg=blue!10,fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=yellow!10,fg=red!70!black}
\setbeamercolor{date}{bg=yellow!10,fg=red!70!black}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % to get rid of nav symbols

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain] % to remove the footline in the title page
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{The title of the frame}
hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gives you:

[image]

[image]

Any time consider that the beamer documentation is there to help you.

Comment: Is it possible to put all this code in a single file and so that I can just import/apply it in every presentation I do? What is the best way/convention to do that? Creating a sty file or having them in tex file and include the tex file?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN: why? If you customize a presentation style and include it in the an appropriate folder of your TeX distribution will all you to use it in any document _without_ importing it every time.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. I will import it. But I don't want to duplicate all these code in every beamer presentation I make.

Comment: Please, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/13304

Comment: Thank you for the great information. I am using theme Warsaw, I want to change the size of one frame, I tried (`
\setlength\pdfpagewidth{16.00cm}%
\setlength\pdfpageheight{12.00cm}%`), the paper size changed but the footnote stayed where it was. How can make the footnote also go to the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 9):

Are you free to define your own layout, or must you follow a corporate design template?

I had to create a presentation in my companies corporate design and the specification was: Use this Powerpoint template..

The easiest solution was to take the Powerpoint-Presentation, save an empty page as pdf and include it as a background picture in my beamer-template.
After that, I did some positioning to define free areas and write title, name, department, date...

Then I had to include the correct font and I had a LaTeX-Corporate-Design template for my presentations.

If this could be a solution for you, please leave a comment and I will look for my beamer definitions and post it here.

Addendum: The background can be changed with:

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{my_pdf_copy_of_empty_ppt_template}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, i'm free to put my own layout. Basically all I need is a watermarked logo in the background, and the colored logo in the corner. Whatever else is easy, I think. But I'm pretty beginner with 'beamer' and I don't know how to do this. Would you please guide me how to do what mentioned (which files to edit, where to include the pics ...etc.)?

Comment: I think [Claudios answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54593/6563) contains already most of the relevant hints. I modified my answer and added an example to modify the background.

Comment: Although this answer is >4 years old, it made my life as a beamer neophyte *much* easier!  Wish I could give you a thousand points!