# Change \headheight in Beamer, Copenhagen

Tags: beamer

I want to increase the \headheight in Beamer, Copenhagen.

I tried, `\setlength{\headheight}{10in}`, did not seem to work.

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54577/how-do-i-customize-beamer-template

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
My previous answer was actually valid with the Sidebar outer theme, it is not as simple with Split, which is used by Copenhagen. It explains the error you got, since `\beamer@headheight` is not defined in Split.

**Answer:**

You can use the following

```
\makeatletter
\newdimen\beamer@headheight
\beamer@headheight=10in

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifnum\@tempdimb<\beamer@headheight
    \setlength{\@tempdimb}{\beamer@headheight}
  \fi
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.125ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%  
}
\makeatother
```

You define a new length `\beamer@headheight` you can modify easily. This is a modification of the Split outer theme that will check if your new head height is larger than the one set by Beamer; if it is true, it will use this new length. If not, it won't change anything to avoid to mess up the headline. If you always want to force the headline to have the `\beamer@headheight` height, you can simply use

```
\makeatletter
\newdimen\beamer@headheight
\beamer@headheight=20pt

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@headheight]{section in head/foot}%
    \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@headheight]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I am getting the following error,

`Undefined control sequence. <argument> \beamer@height \setlength{\beamer@headheight}{10pt}`

Comment: I replied too quickly, it was actually not working with Copenhagen. I edited my answer with a working solution!