# Is it possible to design beamer's themes?

Tags: beamer, themes

With a group of people from my university want to do a new beamer theme about our institution, is it possible? I cannot find any reference about this topic.

For example, on this page http://latex.simon04.net/ , there are a lot of themes.

Comment: It is definitely possible. Take one of these as a starting point: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/theme

Comment: I think you'd better start with [Design a custom Beamer theme from scratch](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146529/13304) and [How do I customize Beamer template?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54577/13304).