# Latex beamer template

Tags: beamer, templates

I would like to know, if there is any latex beamer template that looks as or similar to [this slide presentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150616082543/http://www.sfu.ca/~das3/qt-designer-widgets.pdf).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54577/how-do-i-customize-beamer-template will be a good start.

Comment: Did you look [here](http://latex.simon04.net)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not a default theme for this, but you can easily build something similar; the theme is just a simple variation of the `default` `beamer` theme. Here's a starting point:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{mgreen1}{RGB}{122,197,70}
\definecolor{mgreen2}{RGB}{1,76,47}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=4ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \includegraphics[height=25pt]{Qtlogo}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=4ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=4ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=4ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \includegraphics[height=25pt]{Qtlogo}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[line width=12pt,mgreen1]
  (current page.north west) --
  (current page.north east) --
  (current page.south east) --
  (current page.south west) --
  (current page.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=mgreen2}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=mgreen2!70}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]

\title{Qt Designer Widgets}
\subtitle{Qt Essentials}
\author{Presented by tex.sx}
\institute{Produced by some company}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Objects in Qt}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Questions and Answer}
test
\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
\item First item.
\item First item.
\item First item.
\end{itemize}
\item First item.
\item First item.
\item First item.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I took the logo image `Qtlogo` from [`qt.digia.com`](http://qt.digia.com/Global/About%20Us/Qt_master_logo_CMYK_300dpi.png).