# Titlepage with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles

I need some help with a titlepage for tikz

I want to create the following... 3 red lines, a gray space a green space but I already fail with just creating a line across the whole page...

`\draw (0,0) -- (\pagewidth,0)` fails :-(, it only creates a line of 2 cm or so...

I hope anyone is good with tikz and can create this for me.

[image: reference image]

**Update**

@Tobi I now have the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  calc,
  positioning
}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \coordinate (SW) at (current page.south west);
  \coordinate (SE) at (current page.south east);
  \coordinate (NW) at (current page.north west);
  \coordinate (NE) at (current page.north east);

  % commented out because it is not necessary to compile, 
  % but one should note that the background is here, 
  % because of overlapping parts.
  %\node at ($(current page.south west)$){
  %  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  %    %\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{./figures/cover_spaceshuttle.jpg}
  %  \end{tikzpicture}};  

  \fill[blue,very nearly opaque] ($(SW)!0.2!(SE)$) -| ($(SE)!1.95!(NE)$) -- cycle;
  \fill[red,very nearly opaque] ($(SW)!0.2!(SE)$) -| ($(SE)!1.95!(NE)$) -- cycle;
  \draw[white,fill] ($(SW)$) rectangle ($(SE)!0.1!(NE)$);
  \fill[blue,very nearly opaque] ($(SW)!0.2!(SE)$) -| ($(SE)!1.95!(NE)$) -- cycle;
  \draw[red] ($(SW)!0.20!(SE)$) -- ($(NW)!0.61!(NE)$);
  \draw[red] ($(SW)!0.10!(NW)$) -- ($(SE)!0.10!(NE)$);
  \node at ($(SW)!0.1!(NW)$) [
    anchor=north,
    xshift=6.40cm,
    yshift=0.13cm,
    minimum width=\paperwidth,
    align=center,
    outer sep=0pt,
    font=\sffamily]{something};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

This code generates the following page [image: Current situation and prefered situation]

Now the blue fill fills all the way to the top, on the left side. But I only want to let it fill at about $(SW)!0.05!(NW)$, the right side. How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/exam-sheet/ for an example

Comment: The easiest way to limit the blue part it to clip it. Try `\begin{scope}\clip (SW) rectangle ($(SE)!0.05!(NE)$);\fill[blue,very nearly opaque] ($(SW)!0.2!(SE)$) -| ($(SE)!1.95!(NE)$) -- cycle;\end{scope}`. But I’m not sure if I get you right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the options `overlay` and `remember picture` to make the cooridnates of the current page available as the `current page` node.

Try to adapt this to fit your needs …

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}% [0]

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,line width=5pt]
    % set a new origin [1]
    \coordinate (O) at (current page.south west);
    % gray triangle
    \fill [gray] (current page.south west) -| (current page.north east) -- cycle;
    % red line
    \draw [red] (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east);
    % white framed box
    \node at (current page.south) [%
        draw=red,
        inner sep=15pt,
        fill=white,
        above=5cm,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries\Huge
    ] {The book title};
    % red box at 0.8\pageheight
    \node (Author) at ($(O)+(0,0.8\paperheight)$) [% [2] [4]
        fill=red,
        anchor=south west,
        minimum width=\paperwidth,
        align=center,
        outer sep=0pt,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries] {Jon Doe};
    % red box at 0.75\paperheight
    \node at ($(current page.south)!0.75!(current page.north)$) [% [3]
        fill=red,
        anchor=south,
        minimum width=\paperwidth,
        align=center,
        outer sep=0pt,
        font=\sffamily] {\today};
    % red box above the author
    \node [%
        fill=red,
        above=1mm of Author,% [5]
        minimum width=\paperwidth,
        align=center,
        outer sep=0pt,
        font=\sffamily] {\TeX.SX example press};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: title page]

(Compile twice to get the right result)

**Update**
I added three more ways to position your elements on the page

- Set a new origin coordinate `(O)` to the lower left corner [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swzMs.png) of the page and move relatively [2] to it (needs `calc` library [0]).
- Use TikZ to calculate the position using the `(point)!div!(point)` syntax [3] (needs `calc` library [0]).
- Name a node [4] and position a second node relatively to it [5] (needs `positioning` library [0]).

Comment: Thanks Tobi for your comment. Now for example I want to draw a line at 0.2*pageheight from right to left... How do I do that? It's kinda hard when using current page.center or those kind of coordinates...

I would rather use something like `0.2*\pageheight`

Which I actually tried with using 

> \coordinate (front) at (0,0);
> \coordinate (horizon) at (0,.31\paperheight);
> \coordinate (bottom) at (0,-.6\paperheight);
> \coordinate (sky) at (0,.57\paperheight);
> \coordinate (left) at (-.51\paperwidth,0);
> \coordinate (right) at (.51\paperwidth,0);

Comment: This was my code, it compiles correctly but no line is drawn... can it because I use the geometry package?

`\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \coordinate (left) at (-.51\paperwidth,.31\paperheight); 
  \coordinate (right) at (.51\paperwidth,.31\paperheight);
  \draw[blue] (left) -- (right);
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @Wouter If you can include your minimal example(starting from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` with only relevant packages and the relevant part of the code) we can help you better instead of these iterations.

Comment: @Wouter Try      `\fill[red] (0,0) circle (8pt);` inside Tobi's example to understand your problem. It's more easy to use relativ coordinates with "current page" anchors !

Comment: @Wouter: See my update …

Comment: @Tobi thank you very much I think I can adapt this now to my needs!

Comment: @Tobi I updated my question. Thanks in advance for your help. I commented out the background code because it is not necessary to compile the code, one should only note that the background is there. Otherwise one could solve this by just overlapping parts in the correct order.

Comment: I compiled your example and the whole triangle is shifted up by about 90% of the page height. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Hi, I can’t reproduce this. If I compile my form above I get the intended result. Did you change anything or are there some packages out of date?