# Position image in an arbitrary position in the title page of beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles

I want to modify title page created with LaTeX's `\title{Hello}...\author{hhh}...\date{\today}...\maketitle` command to have a logo in the right top corner, not on any other page. Unfortunately, I haven't succeeded in this so if this is impossible, the second option is to use custom page with `\begin{titlepage}...` and configure everything like typical title page.

### **How can I modify typical LaTeX titlepage to have a logo in the right top corner? Can this be achieved with `\maketitle` or do we need a custom `\begin{titlepage}`?**

*Potentially related*

> 1. [Titlepage with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59672/titlepage-with-tikz)
> 2. [How can I position an image in an arbitrary position in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/how-can-i-position-an-image-in-an-arbitrary-position-in-beamer)

Comment: Please provide a minimal almost-working example (so we can see the document class, etc.).

Comment: @frougon I have tried multiple solutions. I provide two different solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524363/2956) with titlepage and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524363/2956) with `eso-pic` package. There are also other alternatives, returning to the issue and trying to find the best and most convenient solution. I hope someone with more extensive experience would provide their answer and suggestion for the solution.

Comment: Since there was no MWE in your question, I had not noticed it was about `beamer`. I'm not very knowledgeable about this class, I prefer letting `beamer` experts answer. You can probably patch the `\maketitle` command if this is really what you want, but that may be a fragile solution (if the implementation of `\maketitle` were to be modified in the future, you could have unpleasant surprises with the “patching” approach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For positioning of image on the slide you not need `titlepage`, it can be done in any frame. However, you can use it, if its use is more convenient to you in design the title frame.

Absolute positioning in the corners is simple with use of `tikzpicture` and its options  `remember picture` and `overlay`.:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Hello}
\author{hhh}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node [inner sep=0pt,
       %xshift=-..., yshift=-...   % if you like to shift the image out of corner
       below left] 
    at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image-duck}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]