# Adding dynamic information to the right upper edge of beamer template

Tags: beamer

I'm using the AnnArbor template in beamer as follows:

```
\mode<presentation>
{ 
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme[named=kugreen]{structure}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
}
```

And I would like to add a piece of information to some slides, which should be displayed on the top horizontal zone, right edge, as the arrow in the following screen capture shows:

[image]

This information should belong to each frame (it is not a global logo defined once and for all in the preamble), in fact I want to add bibliographical references for the contents of the frame, so it may be different for every frame or void.

What do I need to redefine to obtain this?

ADDITION: Jesse Knight asked for a minimal working example, that would be

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Phonèmes}\infoForRightCorner{Cat01}
Contents of the slide
\end{frame}
```

where “Cat01” should appear on the upper right corner of the slide (same height and font size as the section title “Phonétique / phonologie” which you can see in the blue part of the top horizontal bar) of this slide. This should serve as a reminder that the main bibliographic reference for this slide is “Cat01”, namely J.C. Catford, *A Practical Introduction to Phonetics*, Oxford University Press 2001. Another (maybe more elegant) syntax could be

```
\begin{frame}[fragile,topbarright={Cat01}]
\frametitle{Phonèmes}
Contents of the slide
\end{frame}
```

but for me the result matters more than the syntax to obtain it.

Comment: Please could you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: dear @JesseKnight I just added a minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `infolines` headline definition (found in `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty`), you can redefine the headline such that the top right box is blank. You can then define an option `myinfo` that, if passed to the frame, will redefine the headline such that the content of `myinfo` appears in the box at top-right.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{ 
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
}

%% Make top right box blank for each new frame
\makeatletter
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}
%    \insertsubsectionhead
\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}}

%% If myinfo option is passed to frame, add to headline
\define@key{beamerframe}{myinfo}[true]{%
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}
    #1
%    \insertsubsectionhead
\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

\section{Phonétique / phonologie}
\subsection{First subsection title}

\begin{frame}[fragile,myinfo=Cat01 or something]
\frametitle{Phonèmes}
Slide with info
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Next frame}
No info for this slide
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using Tikz: place a node in the top right (technically: `north east`) corner of the page. Some other options are here: [How can I position an image in an arbitrary position in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/how-can-i-position-an-image-in-an-arbitrary-position-in-beamer)

[Note: in the example below, I had to invent the `kugreen` colour. It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal working example in future, which means the contents of a TeX file that other users could copy and paste and immediately compile, without adding `\documentclass{...}` and so on.]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{kugreen}{RGB}{50,93,61}
\mode<presentation>
{ 
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme[named=kugreen]{structure}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
}
\newcommand{\infoForRightCorner}[1]{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {#1};}
    }
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Phonèmes}
\infoForRightCorner{Cat01}
Contents of the slide

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```