# How can I position a picture precisely on a page?

Tags: graphics, positioning

I’m new to Latex and I’m trying to place a picture (my university’s logo) at an exact spot on my titlepage. For this, I would like to specify the coordinates on the page at which I would like the picture to be placed.

Up to now, I have written the following code, but it doesn’t work.

```
\documentclass{article}
%...
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
%...
\begin{picture} (10cm, 10cm) (0cm, 0cm)
\put(0.5cm, 0.5cm) {\includegraphics [width=5cm]{logo}} 
\end{picture}
%...
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{titlepage}
%...
\end{document}
```

When I compile it (Pdftex, using TeXShop), the following error message appears:

```
./Sans-titre.tex:56: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
               \setbox 
l.56    \begin{picture} (10cm, 10cm) (0cm, 0cm)
```

Also, I will need to write some text and draw lines at specific spots on my title page, and I fear I will encounter the same problems.

Comment: Use `textpos` package, as described here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/absolute-positioning-in-beamer/6191#6191

Comment: If you are using TikZ and the `remember picture` option to `tikzpicture` you can place the logo in a `\node` positioned relative to the `current page` coordinate.

Comment: How do you want your title page to look like? Can you post a picture of what exactly you have in mind (may be using some other editor like word)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are mixing two graphic systems (tikz and the original picture environment of latex). With tikz you should place graphics (and text) with nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node[anchor=north west, %anchor is upper left corner of the graphic
      xshift=5cm, %shifting around
      yshift=-5cm] 
     at (current page.north west) %left upper corner of the page
     {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{tiger}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```