# How can I prevent footnotes in beamer from inserting a blank slide?

Tags: beamer

When a footnote is created in beamer that contains a box whose depth is too great, beamer inserts a blank slide before the slide with the footnote.

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbox0=\hbox{}
\dp0=1.131ex
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\footnote{\box0 }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If I change the `1.131ex` to `1.130ex`, there is only one slide.

My actual problem doesn't involve an empty box with an artificial depth (of course). I can work around this issue by putting the material with the too-great depth into a box and set its `\dp` to `0pt`, but this seems like the wrong solution in general.

What is the correct method to prevent an extra slide from being inserted in this case?

Comment: Interestingly, one my TeXLive2017 installation I always get one page, even if I increase `1.31ex` like crazy.

Comment: Which tex distribution do you have and which engine are you using?

Comment: @samcarter TeXLive 2017 using pdflatex.

Comment: @TH. Me too. Can you post the log file of the MWE?

Comment: @samcarter Sure. sharelatex exhibits the same behavior if you want to play around with it.

Comment: @samcarter The log is too large to include in the question. I put it on pastebin https://pastebin.com/g5h2jnpq

Comment: @TH. Thanks for the log. The problem is your beamer version. I am able to reproduce the problem with the version you use, but it works fine with the current version. Can you update to the current version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This briefly worked in beamer v3.55, which can be checked out from https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/releases/tag/v3.55

#### Workaround for beamer v3.54 or older:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbox0=\hbox{}
\dp0=1.131ex

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@doseveralframes#1{%
  \ifx\beamer@againname\@empty\else%
    % Again stuff
    \expandafter \gdef\csname beamer@again@\beamer@againname\endcsname{{#1}}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@slideinframe=1\relax%
  \loop%
  \beamer@anotherslidefalse%
  \gdef\beamer@doifnotinframe{}%
  \def\beamer@doifinframe{\begin{beamer@frameslide}%
    #1%
  \end{beamer@frameslide}}%
  \beamer@masterdecode{\beamer@whichframes}%
  \beamer@donow%
  \ifbeamer@twoscreenstext%
    \beamer@dosecondscreennow{#1}% two screen stuff
  \fi%
  \ifbeamer@anotherslide
  \advance\beamer@slideinframe by 1\relax
  \repeat%
  \beamer@writeslidentry%
  \beamer@reseteecodes}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\footnote{\box0 }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Workaround for beamer v3.56 or newer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbox0=\hbox{}
\dp0=1.131ex

\makeatletter
% The main decoding macro tolerates a range of active characters, which
% require a little set up. In particular, as an active space is allowed
% all of the lines here have to be terminated with "%". The two-step
% setup for \beamer@@@temp makes sure everything is expanded and removes
% all of the spaces at this stage.
\newbox\beamer@decode@box
\begingroup
  \catcode`\|=\active
  \catcode`\:=\active
  \catcode`\,=\active
  \catcode`\.=\active
  \catcode`\+=\active
  \catcode`\-=\active
  \catcode`\(=\active
  \catcode`\)=\active
  \catcode`\ =\active
\xdef\beamer@masterdecode#1{%
\noexpand\beamer@localanotherslidefalse%
\setbox0=\hbox{%
\unexpanded{%
\ifnum\catcode`\|=\active\edef|{\string|}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\:=\active\edef:{\string:}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\,=\active\edef,{\string,}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\.=\active\edef.{\string.}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\+=\active\edef+{\string+}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\-=\active\edef-{\string-}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\(=\active\edef({\string(}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\)=\active\edef){\string)}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\ =\active\edef {\string }\fi}%
\edef\noexpand\beamer@@@temp{#1\string|stop\string:0\string|}%
\edef\noexpand\beamer@@@temp{\unexpanded{\expandafter\zap@space\beamer@@@temp}%
\space\noexpand\@empty}%
\unexpanded{\expandafter\beamer@decode\beamer@@@temp%
\ifbeamer@localanotherslide\aftergroup\beamer@localanotherslidetrue\fi}%
}%
}%
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\footnote{\box0 }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Still having this problem on TeXLive 2020. Fix didn't work neither.

Comment: mmm, looks like this came back sometime between TL2018 and 2019

Comment: it worked prior to https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/523de6fd97b83d2c26a247b94e0fad6302e4ca41

Comment: If it matters, my MWE is slightly different. I am using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244103) `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.north east){%
    \footnotetext{abc};
\end{tikzpicture}` to keep a fixed footnote position. From the `.log` `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) [...] beamer.cls    2020/07/22 v3.59` which might not be the newest, but is a container.

Comment: How are you testing all these versions so quickly?

Comment: @BadAtLaTeXProgramming The wonders of using git for version control :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148221/discussion-between-badatlatexprogramming-and-samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz).

Comment: @BadAtLaTeXProgramming I added a new workaround. I'm not sure what the actual problem is you are trying to solve, but it looks like an xy problem. Maybe you could ask a question about your actual problem?

Comment: I did. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694869). It turned out to be caused by inline math in the aforementioned footnote.