# How avoid empty slide with TikZ-overlay footnote in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, math-mode, footnotes

#### Motivation

I want to maintain a footnote in beamer through some slides. To avoid jumping I tried to place them with TikZ (which works) but the height of the inline math causes empty slides.

#### Question

How can I maintain my awfully high footnote line without any empty pages?

###### `MWE.tex`

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\mode<presentation>
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Intro}
  Hello
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide Title}
    \begin{theorem}
    Some theorem \footnotemark[1] to break the ice
    \end{theorem}
    % footnote
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/absolute-positioning-in-beamer?rq=1
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node at (current page.south west){%
      \footnotetext[1]{
          % {\footnotesize
              where $E =M \Big\lvert_{y =\zeta( x )}C^2$ 
          }
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Proof Slide}
    \begin{proof}
    Its proof ... where I want to keep the footnote
    \end{proof}
    % footnote
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at (current page.south west){%
        \footnotetext[1]{
                where $E =M \Big\lvert_{y =\zeta( x )}C^2$ 
            }
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I don't see any jumping in the footnote, so I'm not convinced that the absolute positioning with tikz is necessary. And even if, I doubt that a tikz picture wrapped around the outside of `\footnotetext` would be able to influence the position of the footnote text...
- instead of manually adding the footnote to subsequent frames, you could use a single frame and replace the theorem with the proof in overlays.
- a quick hack to avoid the empty pages: hide the height of the math with `\smash{...}` (to move the footnote rule up, you can then manually increase the height of the footnote with an invisible rule)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle<1>{Slide Title}
\frametitle<2>{Proof Slide}
    \begin{theorem}<only@1>
    Some theorem where\footnote{\rule{0pt}{3ex}\smash{$E =M \Big\lvert_{y =\zeta( x )}C^2$}}  to break the ice
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}<only@2>
    Its proof ... where I want to keep the footnote
    \end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd rather stick with seperate frames inorder to increse the frame counter accordingly. However, `\smash{}` solves the problem anyways.

Comment: @BadAtLaTeXProgramming You could use one frame and show the page number instead of the frame number

Comment: Locally? Since it would be fine here but in other places I wouldn't want 10 increments for 10 listed elements that I just want to show one after another.

Comment: @BadAtLaTeXProgramming Ah, locally would be difficult. One could change the template locally, but if there overlay frames before it, the frame and page number would already be out of sync.

Comment: Well nevermind it, as I've said before it perfectly works also with the absolute positioning of TikZ. Though you are right, it ends up in the same spot independent of TikZ-settings. I assume that is because the `remember picture, overlay` combined with current page capture that respective size and footnote always goes to the bottom of the page/area. That is fine though; currently.