# customizing slides on beamer

Tags: beamer

I  have a slide on powerpoint and I want to switch to beamer, to look like this:

[image]

Any ideas? I am stuck and I'll appreciate any help.

I tried this code :

```
    \begin{frame}{TEST101}

\begin{textblock*}{3cm}(0.4cm,2.5cm) % {block width} (coords)
\includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{figs/effet.png}
\end{textblock*}
\begin{columns}[T] % align columns
\begin{column}{.40\textwidth}

\end{column}%

\begin{textblock*}{3cm}(4cm,7cm) % {block width} (coords)
\includegraphics[width=9.5cm]{figs/image11.png}
\end{textblock*}
\hfill%
\begin{column}{.50\textwidth}

\begin{itemize}
    \item La fibre multimode à saut d'indice est utilisée dans les réseaux locaux.
    \item Il existe plusieurs modes de propagation de la lumière au sein de son cœur.
    \item La fibre à saut d'indice possède un cœur très large.
    \item Tous les rayons lumineux n’ont pas  la même vitesse.
\end{itemize}
\end{column}%
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

but  I am getting this instead:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us the TeX code you have tried so far?

Comment: I edited  the question  I added the code that I used and the screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a template that is close to your case. I put references in the code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% Also provides "example-image-a", see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738
\usepackage{graphicx}

% for "tikzpicture"
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame Title}

% See beamer manual (https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer), Section 12.7 Splitting a Frame into Multiple Columns
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
% Left column, empty
\end{column}
\begin{column}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
% Right column, list
\begin{itemize}
    \item Text text text text
    \item Text text text text
    \item Text text text text
    \item Text text text text
    \item Text text text text
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6185
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture] 
% Top left picture
    \node at (current page.north west)[
        anchor = north west, 
        inner sep = 0pt, 
        outer sep = 0pt,
        xshift = 20mm,
        yshift = -20mm]{
        \includegraphics[width = 30mm]{example-image-a}   
        };
% Bottom picture
    \node at (current page.south)[
        anchor = south, 
        inner sep = 0pt, 
        outer sep = 0pt,
        xshift = 0mm,
        yshift = 10mm]{
        \includegraphics[width = 30mm]{example-image-b}   
        };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: THank you it's working you saved me