# drawing a vertical line in a page border

Tags: graphics, border

I could draw a border for a page with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

How can I draw a vertical line (red line) in the below picture:

[image]

Comment: You can do this similar to [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678111/277964) using a `\rule` or `\line` instead of the image and package `color` or `xcolor` to select the color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easy with `eso-pic` package and a simple `\rule`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \hspace{1.5cm}\color{red}\rule{.1cm}{\paperheight}%
    }
    
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful and excelent!!!!

Comment: You solved my big problem

Comment: @Irreversible Thank you for accepting my answer!