# inclined line in the corner of a document

Tags: graphics, border

How can I insert four inclined lines in the corner of page border?

Does someone have any experience in this field?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to insert image on page at the bottom-left of a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678043/how-to-insert-image-on-page-at-the-bottom-left-of-a-page) To replace the images shown in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678111/277964) just replace the `\includegraphics` by either `picture` code or TikZ code for the lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply adapt [my code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678111/277964) from [how to insert image on page at the bottom-left of a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678043/how-to-insert-image-on-page-at-the-bottom-left-of-a-page/678111#678111). You just have to replace the `\includegaphics` code in these examples by either corresponding `picture` environment code or by [TikZ](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) code. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}% color would also be sufficient
\usepackage{calc}% For not needing \dimexpr in my \put and \line commands.
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{plain}

\DeclareNewLayer[%
  background,%
  mode=picture,%
  page,
  contents={%
    \color{red}\thicklines
    \put(0,\paperheight-5cm){\line(2,3){5cm*2/3}}%
    \put(\paperwidth,\paperheight-5cm){\line(-2,3){5cm*2/3}}%
    \put(0,5cm){\line(2,-3){5cm*2/3}}%
    \put(\paperwidth,5cm){\line(-2,-3){5cm*2/3}}%
  }%
]
{cornerimages}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{cornerimages}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Would result in:

[image: Example image with red lines "cutting" the upper left, upper right, lower left and lower right corner of the paper]

You can adapt all other examples in my answer by similar code. Alternatively you can adapt [the TikZ answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244103/277964) to: [Absolute positioning in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6185/277964).