Alternating pages
I want alternating pages ... with wide outer margin ... outer margins to contain light dotted lines spaced say 0.2in apart filling entire space.  Text side to contain text (I'll do formatting later) with a thin colored border (small corners) around it.
what I have so far:
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paper=a4paper,
  inner=2cm,
  outer=10cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
}

\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Methods}
\lipsum[4-6]

\section{Results}
\lipsum[7-9]

\section{Discussion}
\lipsum[10-12]

\end{document}

Maybe with tikz?

Can you show an image or sketch of what you want? And yes, you can make lines etc. using TikZ. And to put them in the margin you can use generic hooks or several package as show, e.g., here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678111/277964. And for text with borders you can also use TikZ or tcolorbox or \framebox or …

what do you mean by 'small corners'?

small rounded corners

Do you want something like this.
There is a command \AddToHook {shipout/background}{} that allows you to add something to every page. Combining this with tikz gives you
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paper=a4paper,
  inner=2cm,
  outer=10cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
}

\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text

\usepackage{tikz}

%% Line in the margin
\AddToHook {shipout/background}%
        { \ifodd\value{page}\relax%
            \put (12cm,-1in){\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]%
                \foreach \y in {1,2,...,48}%
                \draw[dotted] (0,-0.2in*\y) --++ (8cm,0);%
                \end{tikzpicture}}%
        \else%
            \put (1cm,-1in){\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]%
                \foreach \y in {1,2,...,48}%
                \draw[dotted] (0,-0.2in*\y) --++ (8cm,0);%
                \end{tikzpicture}}%
        \fi%
      }

%% Box around text
\AddToHook {shipout/background}%
        { \ifodd\value{page}\relax%
            \put (1.5cm,-2cm){\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]%
                \draw[rounded corners=10mm] (0,0) rectangle++ (\textwidth+1cm,\textheight+1cm);%
                \end{tikzpicture}}%
        \else%
            \put (9.5cm,-2cm){\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]%
                \draw[rounded corners=10mm] (0,0) rectangle++ (\textwidth+1cm,\textheight+1cm);%
                \end{tikzpicture}}%
        \fi%
      }

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Methods}
\lipsum[4-6]

\section{Results}
\lipsum[7-9]

\section{Discussion}
\lipsum[10-12]

\end{document}

The \put command places the mandatory argument at the specified coordinate.
I placed 48 lines spaced by 0.2in, but this can be modified to fit your need.
The rounded corners are at 5mm to not interfere with dotted lines. If you need it to be bigger, use the \clip command to hide the dotted line.
The final result is:



I actually want the border around the text and nothing around dotted lines

And/or maybe a version with NO borders ... AND the separation between columns smaller

Thanks so far!  I had played with these packages along the way and was not quite getting it right

My intended deployment of this is to have something akin to a "Poor Man's Spiral Bible" which could just be printed and have a binding added ... seems to be issues when I do an \input{file.tex} which would be the final modular configuration

@user2796901 I misunderstood your question, so I updated my answer. You can play with every dimensions and see the result. If you want the box to be closer to the text, or farther away. Same for the dotted lines.

what's a 'spiral bible'?

If you are doing this on every page for a document of any length, drawing a tikzpicture every time will drastically slow compilation. There are at least three general strategies for avoiding this:

Externalise the pictures as including images is much faster.
Save the picture to a box and reuse the box. In this case, 2 boxes (one for odd and even or else one for each side of the page.)
Avoid using tikz (or pgf). Nothing in your list of desiderata requires anything which can't be done with LaTeX's picture mode, except for colour which would require color or (better) xcolor if required.

The following mixes strategies 2 and 3.

For the frames, we use tikz because LaTeX's code produced horrible results when I tried it. (Well, maybe 'horrible' is an exaggeration, but they were not at all pretty.) We create two frames at the start of the document: one to frame text and one to frame dots. Whether these are actually used depends on two conditionals, but you can comment what you don't need. The overhead for creating very simple pictures like these just once is minimal - the cost here is in loading tikz in the first place - so we don't bother with strategy 1.
We use LaTeX for the dots. Really, I should save the dots to a box rather than reputting them, but this still seems fast to me. If you go with a tikz solution, though, you should definitely consider boxing and reusing the picture.

Configuration: the commented section at the end of the preamble explains how to modify the colours of dots and frames, the line spread and the allowance between the lines and the paper edge. You could also adjust the distance between the text and lines as this version just uses \columnsep. If you do this, use geometry's option so it is accounted for in your page layout. Note that, by default, the distance from the paper edge is equal to \columnsep, so if you want to change one but not the other, you will need to set this explicitly.
I don't particularly like the result, but magenta is probably not the best choice and neither is double-framing1.

\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}
% ateb: % ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726457/
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  inner=2cm,
  outer=10cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength\mlinessep
\newlength\mlinesmargin
\newsavebox\mframetxtbox
\newsavebox\mframedotsbox
\newif\ifmframetxt
\newif\ifmframedots
\AddToHook{begindocument}
{%
  \newlength\mlinelength
  \setlength\mlinelength{\dimexpr\evensidemargin+2.54cm-\mlinesmargin-\columnsep}%
  \newlength\mlinesdrop
  \setlength\mlinesdrop{\dimexpr\topmargin+\headheight+2.54cm+\headsep+\textheight}%
  \newlength\mlinesoddindent
  \setlength\mlinesoddindent{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+2.54cm+\textwidth+\columnsep}%
  \newlength\mframedrop
  \setlength\mframedrop{\dimexpr\mlinesdrop-0.5\textheight}%
  \newlength\mframetxtoddindent
  \newlength\mframetxtevenindent
  \setlength\mframetxtevenindent{\dimexpr\evensidemargin+2.54cm+0.5\textwidth}%
  \setlength\mframetxtoddindent{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+2.54cm+0.5\textwidth}%
  \newlength\mframedotsoddindent
  \newlength\mframedotsevenindent
  \setlength\mframedotsevenindent{\dimexpr\mlinesmargin+0.5\mlinelength}%
  \setlength\mframedotsoddindent{\dimexpr\mlinesoddindent+0.5\mlinelength}%
  \newsavebox\mline
  \newcounter{mlinecount}%
  \edef\tempa{\fpeval{\textheight/\mlinessep}}%
  \def\mkint#1.#2nil{#1}%
  \edef\tempb{\expandafter\mkint\tempa.#2nil}%
  \setcounter{mlinecount}{\tempb}%
  \sbox\mline{%
    \hbox to \mlinelength {%
      \leaders \hbox to 0.333em {\hss \textcolor{mlinescol}{.}\hss} \hfill \kern 0pt
    }%
  }%
  \AddToHook{shipout/background}
  {%
    \ifodd\value{page}%
      \multiput(\mlinesoddindent,-\mlinesdrop)(0,\mlinessep){\themlinecount}{\usebox\mline}%
      \ifmframetxt
        \put(\mframetxtoddindent,-\mframedrop){\usebox\mframetxtbox}%
      \fi
      \ifmframedots
        \put(\mframedotsoddindent,-\mframedrop){\usebox\mframedotsbox}%
      \fi
    \else
      \multiput(\mlinesmargin,-\mlinesdrop)(0,\mlinessep){\themlinecount}{\usebox\mline}%
      \ifmframetxt
        \put(\mframetxtevenindent,-\mframedrop){\usebox\mframetxtbox}%
      \fi
      \ifmframedots
        \put(\mframedotsevenindent,-\mframedrop){\usebox\mframedotsbox}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}
% kernel drawing is either 'highly experimental' or produces poor quality results for rounded corners, so use tikz for frames
% to avoid needless overhead, draw the frame only once
\AddToHook{begindocument}{%
  \sbox\mframetxtbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),overlay]
      \node (mframe) [draw=mframecol,rounded corners,text width=\textwidth,text height=\textheight,text depth=0pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  \sbox\mframedotsbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),overlay]
      \node (mframe) [draw=mframecol,rounded corners,text width=\mlinelength,text height=\textheight,text depth=0pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text
% configuration
% the distance between dotted lines
\setlength\mlinessep{0.2in}
% the distance between the edge of the paper and the dotted lines
\setlength\mlinesmargin{\columnsep}
% frame colour
\colorlet{mframecol}{magenta}
% dot colour
\colorlet{mlinescol}{gray}
% frame text?
\mframetxttrue
% \mframetxtfalse
% frame dots?
\mframedotstrue
% \mframetxtfalse
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Methods}
\lipsum[4-6]

\section{Results}
\lipsum[7-9]

\section{Discussion}
\lipsum[10-12]

\end{document}

1But I also tend not to like frames for everything. I prefer to reserve them for specific information which should be highlighted for particular attention. So this may be just my preference.

This is spectacular! Begging an indulgence, how to add color border around dotted lines?

And lighter dots?

@user2796901 do you want the border around the text or the lines? you said the text in your comment on the other answer and in the question, but the lines in your comment just above.

either! Options would be useful!

@user2796901 see edit above

THis is great any a number of people will find it useful ... Now if I want to insert normal single column pages, how to do that? (You've already answered quite enough and I am grateful)

@user2796901 where it says \AddToHook{shipout/background} make it \AddToHook{shipout/background}[mylabel]. then you can say \RemoveFromHook{shipout/background}{mylabel}. an alternative would be to add another conditional. but I suspect we might be getting to the point where some kind of actual user interface would be better. that seems like a followup question, since it wasn't mentioned in your original post. It might be clearer to keep the answers here focused on the core issue. what do you think?

OK ... no time at the moment

@user2796901 no rush ;).

Will this approach work in the book class?

I also would like to have "regular" text pages before the frames

@user2796901 it should work fine with book, yes. re. the second question: you could set up commands to switch the frames on and off at will.

Ok ... great ... what would such a command look like?

@user2796901 I really think you should ask a followup as this wasn't part of your original question. you could edit the question, but that would partly invalidate existing answers. I can edit mine, but then it would look as if the other answer ignored part of your question. otherwise, if I edit to answer your comment, I'm answering something there's no question for. so I'd really prefer you to ask a followup and link to this question. if you want me to look, feel free to add a link to the comments here. but you may get better answers from others anyway :-).

FIne ... How do I attach things like pdfs or .tex files to a posting? (I'm farirly new here)

@user2796901 you paste .tex files as inline code and convert pdf to one or more images (jpg or png).
