How to Position a Comment in the Lower Right Hand Corner of the Page?
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\textheight=5in
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1]
\parskip 10pt
\textbf{Place at lower right hand corner of this page.}
\end{document}

output:

How may one automatically place a comment at the lower right-hand corner of a given page?

This question is similar to: Controlling the exact position of objects on a page. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@cabohah I don't think that is a useful duplicate. That question specifically asks how to do something similar on an older installation. By now, that is a much older installation. So an answer to that question can't reasonably use the best methods of achieving the same result now. So not only are there better answers now to this question, they aren't answers to the proposed duplicate.

@cfr texpos can still be used for absolute positioning. And I've already linked to my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678043/how-to-insert-image-on-page-at-the-bottom-left-of-a-page/678111, which shows several more alternative, i.e., using generic hooks, today. Always linking the same question/answer is tiring, sorry. ;-)

@cfr No, not a footer. Actually, the real comment might be two simple words, such as "Latex inside." I would like to be able to designate on a particular page, that this message should appear on the page in the lower right-hand corner.

So maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678043/how-to-insert-image-on-page-at-the-bottom-left-of-a-page is the better duplicate.

slight clean up.

A simple answer:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1]
\vfill\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
\raggedleft Latex inside
\end{minipage}
\end{document}

with output:


@cfr Why did you delete your answer? I recall you most certainly had the "Latex inside" at the correct position. Moreover, I would say this "automatically" places the desired comment at the lower right hand corner  of the page since it  works with no trial and error; and, is independent of the amount of space remaining at the end of the last paragraph.

because I obviously misunderstood your question, so it isn't an answer to the actual question you asked. your own answer makes it clear you want this in the text block and that's very different from what I suggested.
